# bundled css is added at the top of index.html

Tags: css, angular

When building a prod version of my Angular 9.0.4 app the css is bundled and added at the top of the dist/index.html like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.6ea28d52542acb20a4c6.css"><!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MyTitle</title>
  <base href="/">
```

Which I think is causing the warning in Chrome:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:
```

and the stylesheet is not rendered correctly. Note this happens only when loading the domain with subfolders e.g. `www.mydomain.com/product/1`

Is it possible to configure the build such that the stylesheet element is added below `<base href="/">` which would possibly fix the warning?

Comment: Proper order is:  `<!doctype html> <html> <head> <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.6ea28d52542acb20a4c6.css">`

Comment: I am unfamiliar with Angular, but you probably need to post the build file to get a proper answer: [reprex]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to move the css file import, but you can stop this error by turning off css extraction:

yarn build --extractCss=false

OR inside your build configurations in angular.json

```
{
 ...
 "build": {
  "configurations": {
    "yourBuildName": {
      ...
      "extractCss": false
    }
  }
 }
}
```